# How to combine two datasets to create training data

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I am working on a problem where I have say dataset 1 (D1) and dataset 2 (D2), now D1 has three features F1, F2, F3, and D2 has four features F1, F2, F3, and F4. The number of samples in D1 is 7000 and in D2 there are 140000 now I want to know what is the best way to combine these two datasets and create say D3 = pd.concat(D1, D2, axis=0). What are some industry-standard ways of these combining datasets?
I believe I can look at the distribution of D2(F4) and assume that D1(F4) will have a similar distribution and then I can generate samples for D1(F4) but is this correct can I do this or should I try something else?

Comment: Is `F1` from  `D1` the same feature (but different values) as in `D2`?

Comment: Yes it is the same feature you can consider F1 to say "Marks obtained in mathematics" D1 will contain marks of the students in say year 2021 and D2 will contain marks of the students in 2022.